# FadeIn fadeOut images with a wrapper div

Tags: jquery, html, containers, fadein, fadeout

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/15/)

This code works fine without the wrapper div

```
$('div').click(function () {
```

but when I use the wrapper div

```
$('.wrapper').click(function () {
```

the other two images fadeIn and fadeOut when I don't want them to. I only want them to "toggle" when they are set to their "second" images.

So, the black empty circle should fade back to the red circle when the blue circle is clicked.

This is the old functionality that worked fine.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/16/)

I can't get this same functionality to work with the wrapper div applied.

Comment: No, I can get to that point. I can't get that same functionality to work with <div class="wrapper"> wrapping the three divs. I need this wrapper div to seperate this functionality from my other images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$('.wrapper div').click(function () {`

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NpzQm/3/)**

Comment: You forgot the wrapper div in your demo. [Your suggestion worked though](http://jsfiddle.net/NpzQm/2/). Thanks! Enjoy the points.

Comment: :) @StacyM, I posted the wrong link. But great it worked. Glad I could help! Btw, remeber to close your img tags. it dhoule end like ` />`. Corrected the answer's demo also :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - Use this as your selector.  It targets on the div element in the wrapper.
It uses only one listener which is great for performance.

See my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jC8Pf/17/

```
$('div','.wrapper')
```